# Kapparah for a family member who apostatised

Tags: kaparah-atonement, apostasy

Some of my more notable relatives (all since deceased) apostatised, either to protect themselves during the war or for other similarly non-dogmatic reasons. While of course I would discuss any practical ramifications with my rav, I was wondering: is there anything in Ashkenazi halachic literature which discusses what one may do to elevate the neshamah of someone who died an apostate?

Note: I am **NOT** descended from any of these relatives r"l, but due to their notability (some have Wikipedia pages, which I am not linking to so as to avoid bringing greater shame on them) I feel that this would be appropriate.

Comment: How is this different from anyone else who died? Do Mitzvot.

Comment: You mean, in a converso-type sense?

Comment: @DonielF, one I know became a meshumad so that he could be buried with his (goyish) wife. As both were secular and his parents are known to have been frei, I suspect he would qualify as a tinok shenishba. The other was a well-known ballet dancer who converted during WWII and was similarly brought up.

Comment: @DoubleAA, do mitzvot for their own sake, or l'ilui nishmatam?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I don't honestly think I know enough what those really mean, and I bet >99% of Jews are in my boat here (whether or not they know it). Just do Mitzvot like God said. He'll sort out the credits justly. No need to play games with the Mitzva-points.

Comment: are you interested for capara if he is yet alive or only after death?

Comment: @kouty, the relatives I know of who have apostatised are all long since deceased. One helped my family come over from France to the US during the war, so I am indebted to him for my existence! My grandmother could very well have been killed by the "Free" French gov't or the Nazis during the war, her mother's cousin was sold out by someone who knew the family.

Comment: I have onetime heard from a great Rav, who explained that the remembering of the deceased is what is resting, if you remind the goodness, so his goodness is his action on world, if you make good as a consequence of him, so this is a continuation of him. See a very interesting girsa of Gemara Sanhedrin reported by Rabenu Yona in Shaare Teshuva. If someone is tsadik and his father is Rasha, he is called Tsadik Ben Tsadik, and inversely if someone is Rasha is a son of a Tsadik, he is called Rasha Ben Rasha. the rational is that begining from this parent, a good thing result.

Comment: and he is the source of goodness in this world. this is the best answer I know

Answer (score 1):

I want to try to give an element of response, following a couple of texts. The good actions of good persons are what they leave on the earth. If the consequence of the actions of these persons is a good think, it its kapara. Gemara in BB 4a said:

> He (Baba Ben Buta) replied (to Herod who killed wises): As you have extinguished the light of the world, [for so the Rabbis are called] as it is written, For the commandment is a light and the Torah a lamp, go now and attend to the light of the world [which is the Temple, of which] it is written, And all the nations become enlightened by it.
>
> Some report that Baba B`Buta answered him thus: As you have blinded the eye of the world, [for so the Rabbis are called] as it is written, if it be done unwittingly by the eyes of the congregation, go now and attend to the eye of the world, [which is the Temple] as it is written, I will profane my sanctuary, the pride o your power, the delight of your eyes.

Rabbenu Yona reported a statement (congruent to Gemara in Sanhedrin 52b (perhaps was it an other Girsa than our Gemara) [Shaare Teshuva III, 218](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_52052_317.pdf):

> ונאמר (משלי כט) תועבת צדיקים איש עול. ונאמר (שם ה) יראת ה' שנאת רע. ואמרו רשע בן צדיק מותר לקרותו רשע בן רשע. צדיק בן רשע מותר לקרותו צדיק בן צדיק.‏
>
> The wise said that it is allowed to call a Tsadik Ben Rasha Tsadik Ben Tsadik.

Following our Girsa this statement can be infered obviously.

I know that you are not offspring of these persons, but, according to the comment of Rashi about "Ele Toldot Noach Noach", the offspring of Tsadikim are them Maassim Tovim, we can infer: A man who helped Jew to not be killed have some percentage in the Maassim Tovim of this family. And each Mitsva you make adds a credit, and help him to be called Tsadik in such a manner.

A salved B, and B made Maassim Tovim, the MT are as a wish of A, so A has a Tsadik part in his personality. This tsadik part was potential and became effective through B.

I am afraid that this answer seems strange, but for me it's true. The more you make mitsvot and Kiddush Hashem, the more you give them Kappara.